# Silverlight project in Windows universal app (Runtime)

Tags: c#, silverlight, win-universal-app

I am creating universal app, but I want to use parts of older app, wroten in Silverlight 8.1. Is there option how to make cooperate these four projects:

- MyProject.Windows (Windows 8.1)
- MyProject.WindowsPhone 8.1 (Windows Phone 8.1)
- MyProject.Shared
- MyProject.OldSilverlightCodes(Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1)

I want to avoid migrating Silverlight code to Runtime line-by-line, it is just too complex to my skills. Is possible connect them any way, maybe via some converter class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot include a Silverlight project in a Windows Runtime project, and there aren't any automated converters.

In general, the best way to share .Net code across multiple targets is to use a Portable Class Library. Depending on what code you have in the Silverlight project it may be straightforward to extract the shared code to a PCL and then use the same PCL in both projects.

--Rob

Comment: This is correct but let's be honest... the odds of the port being straightforward are very small.  It will be a necessary but frustrating process.  There's a reason there aren't any automated tools.